# Problems with image picker

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to use the image picker dependency, but I am running into a. a bit of a problem.
Here is the function I created for the image picker:

```
 pickImage(ImageSource source)async{
    final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();

   XFile? file =await imagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
   if(file != null){
     return file.readAsBytes();
   }else{
     print('no image selected');
   }
  }
```

this was created in a class called _authController. I then created another function for it to pick from the gallery specifically

```
Uint8List? _image;
  final AuthController _authController = AuthController();

  gallarypick()async{
   Uint8List im = await _authController.pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
   setState(() {
     _image = im;
   });
  }
```

when i called the function, it gave me this error

```
W/DynamiteModule( 3685): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 3685): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 3685): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 3685): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
D/EGL_emulation( 3685): app_time_stats: avg=163941.78ms min=37.00ms max=654994.19ms count=4
D/EGL_emulation( 3685): app_time_stats: avg=1099.78ms min=894.68ms max=1304.88ms count=2
E/flutter ( 3685): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)
E/flutter ( 3685): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:294:7)
E/flutter ( 3685): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3685): #1      MethodChannelImagePicker.getImageFromSource (package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_picker.dart:209:26)
E/flutter ( 3685): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3685): #2      AuthController.pickImage (package:car_app/controllers/auth_controller.dart:12:17)
E/flutter ( 3685): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3685): #3      _SellerSignUpState.gallarypick (package:car_app/signup%20and%20login/seller%20signup%20and%20login/seller_signup.dart:25:19)
E/flutter ( 3685): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3685):
```

I do not understand what is wrong. Help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed the package and tries to execute its code directly, the image_picker package needs to get into native functionalities from the device, so it needs a re-run of your app, not hot restart/reload :

- stop your app from running
- run the `flutter clean` command
- run the `flutter pub get` command

then run your debug app again, and it should work

Answer (score 0):

please add the necessary android permissions like below in android manifest file and let me know if it works

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

please refer to the link below which is of same kind.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17545

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall the app. it will start working then.